# Pandas is a Timestamp within a Period

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, period

I have a timestamp

```
tstamp = pd.to_datetime('01/11/2017')
tstamp
->> Timestamp('2017-01-11 00:00:00')
```

and I have a period

```
per = pd.Period('01/03/2017', 'M')
per
->> Period('2017-01', 'M')
```

I want to know if my timestamp is within my period. Eg is January 11th 2017 (my tstamp) within the period of January 2017 (my per)

```
tstamp in per # doesn't work
pd.Series(tstamp).isin([per]) 
->> TypeError: object of type 'pandas._period.Period' has no len()
```

can't seem to figure it out, and I'd rather NOT do something like:

```
tstamp < per.to_timestamp()+pd.Timedelta(1,'M') & tstamp > per.to_timestamp()
```

simply because it doesn't work well with the rest of the time calculations I'm doing on my data.

Comment: If you convert the Period to a pandas Interval called ival the expression "tstamp in ival" gives you want you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `period.start_time` and `period.end_time` attributes:

```
In [134]: per.start_time
Out[134]: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')

In [135]: per.end_time
Out[135]: Timestamp('2017-01-31 23:59:59.999999999')
```

Demo:

```
In [128]: tstamp = pd.to_datetime(['01/11/2017', '2017-06-01'])

In [129]: tstamp
Out[129]: DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-11', '2017-06-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [130]: (per.start_time <= tstamp) & (tstamp <= per.end_time)
Out[130]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```