# Python - generate a timestamp table in pandas given a date period

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp, period

This is kind of a mixture between these two questions:

[Pandas is a Timestamp within a Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741469/pandas-is-a-timestamp-within-a-period) (because it adds a time period in pandas)

[Generate a random date between two other dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates/) (but I need multiple dates (at least 1 million which I specify with a variable LIMIT))

How can I generate random dates WITH random time between a given date period randomly for a specific given amount?

Performance is rather important for me, hence I chose to go with pandas, any performance boosts are appreciated even if that means using another library.

My approach so far would be the following:

```
tstamp = pd.to_datetime(['01/01/2010', '2020-12-31'])
# ???
```

But I don't know how to randomize between dates. I was thinking of using `randint` for a random unix epoch time and then converting that, but it would slow it down A LOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it is very fast:

```
start = np.datetime64('2017-01-01')
end = np.datetime64('2018-01-01')
limit = 1000000
delta = np.arange(start,end)
indices = np.random.choice(len(delta), limit)
delta[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was to add `str(fake.date_time_between(start_date='-10y', end_date='now'))` into my Pandas DataFrame append logic. I'm not even sure that the `str()` there is necessary.

P.S. you initialize it like this:

```
from faker import Faker
# initialize Faker
fake = Faker()
```